# How do I get the data from a MYSQL data reader into an arraylist in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, arraylist

```
 Try
   Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString)
   conn.Open()
   dbQuery = "select * from main_table"
   myCommand.CommandText = dbQuery
   myCommand.Connection = conn
   Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
   myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
   While myReader.Read()
      row_count = row_count + 1
   End While
   Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
   Finally
      conn.Close()
   End Try

   MessageBox.Show(row_count)
   conn.Close()
```

When I run the above code, it displays the correct row count. However, I am trying to get the data into an arraylist one row at a time. Using the code below does not give me an error but it only reads in the first row and then stops executing.

```
 Try
   Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString)
   conn.Open()
   dbQuery = "select * from main_table"
   myCommand.CommandText = dbQuery
   myCommand.Connection = conn
   Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
   myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
   While myReader.Read()
       For x As Integer = 0 To myReader.FieldCount
          col_array.Add(myReader.GetString(x))
       Next
   End While
   Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
   Finally
      conn.Close()
   End Try

   conn.Close()
```

I don't understand why it is stopping after the first row is read in.

Comment: Why not just fill a DataTable? A DT is specifically designed to hold DB DataRows and you can get the count from it.

Comment: Your for loop uses 0 to FieldCount.. Is it giving you an IndexOutOfRangeException at the end of the first row?

Comment: @Plutonix, I need to use an array.

Comment: @ProGrammer - Thanks it needed to be fieldcount - 1. Please post as answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented:

Iterating from 0 to `FieldCount` will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` which will break after the first row.

```
For x As Integer = 0 To myReader.FieldCount
    col_array.Add(myReader.GetString(x))
Next
```

Change it to end at `myReader.FieldCount - 1` to fix this.